# leaflet loops to check if marker already exists in cluster (so as not to duplicate it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a leaflet map which contains markers for the 10 most populous cities in a country. When a user clicks on a city marker an AJAX call is made. I pass the city lat, lng and country code to an API which returns 5 nearby airports (name, lat, lng). I then loop through the resulting JSON data to place markers for each airport on the map.

My problem is that some cities are near each other and thus a duplicate airport marker is sometimes placed on the map.

I want to prevent duplicate markers on the map. I've tried creating a new array then filtering it but I'm not able to get that working.

I'm also wondering if there is a simpler solution to this problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Relevant code below:

```js
if (map.hasLayer(capCityCluster)) {
  map.removeLayer(capCityCluster);
}
capCityCluster = new L.markerClusterGroup();
map.addLayer(capCityCluster);

var largeCityMarker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(cityLat, cityLng), ({
  icon: cityIcon
})).bindPopup(`<div class="markerContainer"><h3>${cityName}</h3><img class="markerThumbnail" src='${cityThumbnailImg}' onerror="this.style.display='none'"><p class="markerTxtDescription">${cityInfo}</p><div id="city-link"><a href="//${cityUrl}" target="_blank">${cityText}</a></div></div>`, cityOptions).once('click', function(e) {
  map.flyTo(e.latlng, 10);
  $.ajax({
    url: "assets/php/airports.php",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      lat: this.getLatLng().lat,
      lng: this.getLatLng().lng,
      countryCodeA2: borderCountryCode,
    },
    success: function(result) {
      //airport markers
      result.data.capCityAirports.items.forEach(airport => {
        var airportIcon = L.icon({
          iconUrl: 'assets/img/icons/airport.png',
          iconSize: [50, 50],
          popupAnchor: [0, -15]
        });
        airportName = airport.title;
        airportLat = airport.position.lat;
        airportLng = airport.position.lng;
        var airportMarker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(airportLat, airportLng), ({
          icon: airportIcon
        })).bindPopup(airportName);
        capCityCluster.addLayer(airportMarker);
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through all layers in the group and check if a marker with the same latlngs exists:

```
var alreadyExists = false;

var latlng = new L.LatLng(airportLat, airportLng);
capCityCluster.getLayers().forEach((layer)=>{
    if(!alreadyExists && layer instanceof L.Marker && layer.getLatLng().equals(latlng)){
       alreadyExists = true;
    }
});

// if alreadyExists is true, it is a duplicate
if(!alreadyExists){
    var airportMarker = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: airportIcon
    }).bindPopup(airportName);

    capCityCluster.addLayer(airportMarker);
}
```

Also you have a mistake in your marker creation. remove the `()` around the options:

```
var airportMarker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(airportLat, airportLng), >>>(<<<{
          icon: airportIcon
        }>>>)<<<).bindPopup(airportName);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works but I did have to change getLatLngs() to getLatLng() without an 's'. It seems to work this way but am wondering if this will possibly cause an issue at some point?

Comment: This was my mistake, a typo! A marker layer has no `getLatLngs()`, `getLatLng()` is correct